# Pass a list from view context to template and assign it as an array in the template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to pass some list from view context:

```
def list_test(request):
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    context = {'l': l}
    return render(request, 'app/list_test.html', context)
```

to front-end as a JS array:

```
<script>
    let l = {{ l }}
    console.log(l)
</script>
```

This however, logs

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

in the console.

I have tried putting the variable in double quotes:

```
let l = "{{ l }}"
```

but then the variable gets assigned as a one big string and with unwanted encoding:

```
[&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;]
```

Template loop will work:

```
 {% for x in l %}
      console.log("{{x}}")
 {% endfor %}
```

but i don't want to iterate. I want to assign the list at once instead.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Should I somehow use the template loop to split the string into array items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this happens is because Django templates will by default escape characters. For example `&` is replaced with `&amp;`, and `"` with `&quot;`. You can mark content as safe with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).

Furthermore, it is probably better to convert your data to a JSON blob with `json.dumps`, so:

```
import json

def list_test(request):
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    context = {'l': json.dumps(l)}
    return render(request, 'app/list_test.html', context)
```

and render it like:

```
<script>
    let l = {{ l|safe }};
    console.log(l);
</script<
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON:

```
def list_test(request):
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    context = {'l': json.dumps(l)}
    return render(request, 'app/list_test.html', context)
```

and mark the value as safe in the template and parse it:

```
    let l = JSON.parse("{{ l|safe }}");
```